# How to clear text box after clone using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to clone a html input field, my jquery code is:

```
$(".add_field_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.fieldset-content').first().clone().appendTo('.fieldset-clone');

    var rmvBtn = $('.fieldset-content').last().find('.remove-button');

    add_remove_btn(rmvBtn);
});
```

My HTML code that are beeing cloned is:

```
<div class="fieldset-clone" data-count="1">
    <div class="fieldset-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">description</label>
                    <input name="description[]" type="text" class="form-control name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <br>
                <input name="img[]" type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 remove-button"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the user have typed in a value in the field, the value is also cloned.
is there a way to reset the text input filed upon cloning the element?

The .add_field_button is the button that clones the inputfields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the value by setting it to an empty string; `val('')`.

```
$('.fieldset-content').first().clone().appendTo('.fieldset-clone').find('.name').val('');
```

Working example:

```js
$(".add_field_button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.fieldset-content').first().clone().appendTo('.fieldset-clone').find('.name').val('');
  var rmvBtn = $('.fieldset-content').last().find('.remove-button');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset-clone" data-count="1">
  <div class="fieldset-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">description</label>
          <input name="description[]" type="text" class="form-control name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <br>
        <input name="img[]" type="file">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 remove-button"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add_field_button">Add field</button>
```